# "no matching function" initializing class

Tags: c++

I got that message

> no matching function for call to 'main()::MySeqInFileEnumerator::MySeqInFileEnumerator(const char [10])'

when im doing my string matching job.I have to method override existing code.I have to open an input text, and make an abstract file from it, then i have to do an optimistic linsearch.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linsearch.hpp"
#include "seqinfileenumerator.hpp"

using namespace std;

struct MyPair
{
    int azon;
    int osszeg;
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& f, MyPair& df);
};

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& f, MyPair& df)
{

     f >> df.azon >> df.osszeg;
     return f;
}`enter code here`
int main()
{

    class MyLinSearch: public LinSearch <int, true>
    {
        bool Cond(const int& e) const
        {
            return e<=-100000;
        }
    };

    class MySeqInFileEnumerator: public SeqInFileEnumerator <MyPair>
    {



        void Next()
        {
            MyPair dx;
           f >> dx;
           df.azon=dx.azon;
           df.osszeg=dx.osszeg;
           while(dx.azon==df.azon)
           {
               dx.osszeg+=df.osszeg;
               f >> dx;
           }
        }
    };

    MyLinSearch pr;
    MySeqInFileEnumerator t("input.txt");
    pr.AddEnumerator(&t);
    pr.Run();

    if (pr.Found())
    {
    cout << "false " << endl;

         }
         else cout << "true" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The message is telling you that `MySeqInFileEnumerator` doesn't have a constructor taking an array of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the class has no constructor taking a string; yet you try to use one with

```
MySeqInFileEnumerator t("input.txt");
```

Perhaps the base class has a suitable constructor? In that case, you'll need to forward the argument:

```
explicit MySeqInFileEnumerator(char const * name) : 
    SeqInFileEnumerator<MyPair>(name)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a suitable constructor. Something like this:

```
class MySeqInFileEnumerator: public SeqInFileEnumerator<MyPair>
{
public:
    MySeqInFileEnumerator(char const * p) : SeqInFileEnumerator<MyPair>(p) { }

// ...
};
```

(This is assuming your base class has a corresponding constructor. Modify to taste.